# Drupal Commerce: Authorize.net payment from manual order

Tags: 7, commerce, payment-gateways

I would like to handle manual phone orders from my Drupal Commerce site.  But the Authorize.Net rule does not appear in the Payment tab for admin/manually created orders.  It even disclaims this for the SIM/DPM rule I'm using.

So what do I do?  I sense this has something to do with a requirement of SIM/DPM being that credit cards aren't stored locally.  That's ok with me, I just need to run the credit card they gave me on the phone, I don't need it stored.

I really just need to be on the payment step of the checkout form for them.  What is it about the SIM/DPM limitation that prevents me doing that step from the admin page?

Answer (score 0):

It's really just a simple matter that the payment terminal form doesn't fully imitate the checkout form on the front end, so redirected payment methods or direct post payment methods are not going to be supportable there.

Comment: What's different about the terminal form?  I'd like to mod in a solution if you have any clues.  Is the payment provider expecting a hash of some form elements?  There must be a param that can be sent just the same as the checkout form.

Or failing this, can the order be loaded by the checkout form so that payment can be processed over there?

The terminal is useless for my client if payments can't be made.  Thanks!

Comment: The form is just completely different, supporting only the direct handling of input, not any sort of redirected workflow. The Payment module does quite a bit within the Checkout form to accommodate all sorts of redirect payment method requirements that we simply never duplicated to the back end.